# Country Picker for Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Is there any NuGet Package or Component of Country Picker for Xamarin(especially Xamarin.IOS)?

I found some library for Native IOS.

[CountryPicker](https://github.com/nicklockwood/CountryPicker)

[MRCountryPicker](https://github.com/xtrinch/MRCountryPicker)

I want to have similar one to above things in Xamarin

Thanks

Comment: you can create a Binding Library to create a C# wrapper for a native iOS library - see https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/

Comment: @Jason Thanks for reply. It's urgent for me and I don't have experience in creating C# wrapper, can you please create it for me?

Comment: @Passionate.C did my answer help you?

Comment: @ColeXia Not tested yet, I will try it today. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/ColeXm/PickerSample) is my sample.

[image]

CountryPickerBind is **BindingProject**  .

PickerSample is a simple demo which uses the dll , you can run it and see the effect.

Step to use CountryPicker in your project.

1. Build CountryPickerBind
2. Add the reference of dll to your project.(dll locates at bin/Debug/*.dll in CountryPickerBind)

[image]

3. Add the PickerView in storyboard or xib , and make the Class `CountryPicker`

[image]

4. Follow the code in ViewController to assign the delegate.
5. Add the images (Resources/CountryPicker.bundle/*.png);
6. Run!

[image]

Comment: I've tried this and seems work. but it doesn't show flag icons in my project. I see the flags in your test project. how can I fix it?

Comment: @Passionate.C maybe you are missing the step5

Comment: no I added all pngs to my Resources folder.
all pngs from Resources/CountryPicker.bundle/*.png in your test project to Resources/*.png in my project

Comment: @Passionate.C did you see the folder `CountryPicker.bundle`? You can not add pngs directly to Resources folder, because pngs was placed in `CountryPicker.bundle` in  source code and I didn't modify it

Comment: @Passionate.C you can see it here , at line 251 https://github.com/nicklockwood/CountryPicker/blob/master/CountryPicker/CountryPicker.m

Comment: so you mean that I need to add CountryPicker.bundle to my project resources folder?

Comment: Yes, if you don't want the extra folder to wrap your pngs, you need to modify the source code .

Comment: It's ok for me. I can add extra folder. I am not sure this dll will work on release because I got it from debug folder

Comment: It's just what I want. Thanks. I checked it as answered!

Comment: Install your app to real device to test , if not works you can bulid `CountryPickerBind` in release mode and link the dll from release folder.